# Accessing / processing ArrayBuffer @ http client (websocket connection, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I have a websocket connection between 
•   Nodejs server (+ socket.io)
•   Browser

A message is emitted from the server to the browser (Udp message from an Arduino)

```
udpSocket.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {                          
    for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        console.log(msg.readInt8(i)); 
}
    console.log("");     
    io.sockets.emit('message', msg);
});
```

Code in the browser (index.html):

A)
I started with:

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    document.getElementById("ko1").innerHTML = message;
})

<p> Arduino sends: </p>
<p id="ko1"> <br>
```

Result in browser : [object ArrayBuffer]

My conclusion : message is coming in, but must be handled in another way.

B)
Research learned that I have to use a DataView on the Array Buffer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). My code:

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    var uint8 = new Uint8Array(message);
    document.getElementById("ko1").innerHTML = uint8[0];
})
```

Result : no data printed to the browser

Question: what am I doing wrong? I also tried other Data Views, but no success. It’ s driving me mad. Please help.